# Getting 0 instead of null for binary search tree

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I have been trying to clear my binary tree and when doing so I get a 0 instead of null from the code below. The tree is defined to be empty when it references NULL but that's not happening. The error can be seen in the traversing over the tree. How can I change it so that when the second set of numbers are inserted, the 0 doesn't show?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    typedef struct Node{
            int value;
            struct Node * left;
            struct Node * right;

    } Node;

    Node * insert(Node * node, int value){
        if(node == NULL){
            Node *temp;
            temp = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            temp->value = value;
            temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
            return temp;
        }
        if(value >(node->value)){
            node->right = insert(node->right,value);
        }
        else if(value < (node->value)){
            node->left = insert(node->left,value);
        }
        return node;
    }

    void inorder(Node * node){
        if(node == NULL) {
            return;
        }
        inorder(node->left);
        printf("%d ", node->value);
        inorder(node->right);
    }

    void preorder(Node * node){
            if(node == NULL){
                return;
            }
            printf("%d ",node->value);
            preorder(node->left);
            preorder(node->right);
    }

    void postorder(Node *node){
            if(node == NULL){
                return;
            }
            postorder(node->left);
            postorder(node->right);
            printf("%d ",node->value);
    }

   /* issue here is produces a 0 instead of null and that can be seen in the traversing :( */
    void empty(Node * node) {
        if (node->left)
            node->left = NULL;
        if (node->right)
            node->right = NULL;
        if (node->value)
            node->value = NULL;
        node->value = NULL;
    }

    int main(){

            Node * root = NULL;
            root = insert(root, 5);
            root = insert(root, -1);
            root = insert(root, 3);
            root = insert(root, -14);
            root = insert(root, 8);
            root = insert(root, 10);
            root = insert(root, 9);
            root = insert(root, 6);

            inorder(root);
            printf("\n");
            preorder(root);
            printf("\n");
            postorder(root);
            printf("\n");

            empty(root);

            root = insert(root, 1);
            root = insert(root, 2);       
            root = insert(root, 3); 

            inorder(root);
            printf("\n");
            preorder(root);
            printf("\n");
            postorder(root);
            printf("\n");      

    }
```

Comment: By the way, your code leaks memory. Your `empty` function should recursively walk through the tree and `free` the nodes before setting the pointers to those nodes to `NULL`.

Comment: `NULL` is defined as `(void *)0`

Comment: `NULL` is defined as an implementation defined null poiter constant. Valid often seen examples are: `((void*)0)`, `0` and `__builtin_null`. The first two have complementary advantages and disadvantages for bug searching, the last one combines their advantages and adds to them.

Comment: How do you "see" a difference between `0` and `NULL`? is this a hoax? We are not on April 1st, yet, aren't we?

Comment: @Jens: Try to assign (void*)0 to an int, and you'll see. This is a quality of implementation issue.

Comment: @Deduplicator, He doesn't say he's has difficulties in assigning `NULL` to an `int`, he says he "gets a 0 from the code".

Comment: @Jens: Please read a) the standard, b) sergeys comment and c) your comment between mine. Then compare and contrast, and remember that _this answer goes to someone who tries to learn C_.

Answer (score 1):

```
void empty(Node ** node) {
    if(*node){
        empty(&(*node)->left);
        empty(&(*node)->right);
        free(*node);
        *node = NULL;
    }
}
...
//at main
empty(&root);
```

Answer (score 0):

You assign NULL to `value`, but `value` is `int` so the NULL ptr gets converted to `int` type – and the result of such conversion is a number zero.

By the way, assigning NULL to the pointer variable replaces the value of the pointer, but **does not** release the memory block, which the pointer was pointing at.

Comment: Not guaranteed according to standard. It could also be diagnosed as a warning or error.

Comment: @Deduplicator: not guaranteed by a standard, but a fact in this case (and in several implementationc of C as well). And I try to explain this case, not the standard in general.

Comment: As it is an answer to a newbie (and also, because others will find it), you should really add a big disclainer "only works in this one instance", or mention the specific additional assumptions. I assume you want to help him learn.