# C - empty binary search tree then insert after that

Tags: c

Not clearing binary tree properly and producing the addresses and a null 0.0 where the root was. When it inserts all it does insert it and the remaining null pointing (uncleared nodes).

How can I properly clear the binary tree?

The code is as follows.

```
void empty(Node * node) {
    Node * left = node->left;
    Node * right = node->right;
    free(node);
    if (left)
        empty(left);
    if (right)
        empty(right);
}

Node * insert(Node * node, int value){
    if(node == NULL){
        node = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        node->value = value;
        node->left = NULL;
        node->right = NULL;
        return node;
    }
    if(value > node->value){
        node->right = insert(node->right,value);
    }
    else if(value < node->value){
        node->left = insert(node->left,value);
    }
    else {
      return;
    }
  return node;
}

void inorder(Node * node){
    if(node == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    inorder(node->left); 
    printf("%.1f ", (float) node->value);
    inorder(node->right); 
}

int main() {
Node * root = NULL;

root = insert(root, 5);
root = insert(root, -1);
root = insert(root, 3);
root = insert(root, -14);
root = insert(root, 8);
root = insert(root, 10);

empty(root);
insert(root, 6);
inorder(root);
}
}
```

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz How can I properly clear the binary tree?

Comment: `free()` all nodes recursively and set `root` to `0`.

Comment: Tip: Make `empty()` a noop on an empty tree, don't let it crash. Might make it return the tree (`0`), like the rest.

Comment: @Deduplicator a noop?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22766131/971127

Comment: noop = no-operation. Do nothing function/op code/thngy... It is surprising how often doing nothing is right.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I have tried that option and got a print of 0.0 (a TON of times) then a segmentation fault.

Comment: @Deduplicator so you mean to just set the node (root) to NULL?

Comment: Setting the node to NULL is one part you left out, checking for it already being Null the other. Also, the insert after emptying the tree is wrong at the moment.

Comment: @Deduplicator would the setting the node to NULL be at the beginning of the empty or before the free(node). I'm rather new to this and don't understand where that should be implemented. Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: Setting to NULL / freeing only after using, if you can. Unless using temporaries lets you avoid recursion. Also, never try setting things to right, if you throw it away immediately afterwards anyway.

Comment: @user3362954 after empty, in the main function set root to NULL. setting root to NULL inside empty will give you nothing, as you pass root by value

Comment: `insert(root, 6);` --> `root = insert(root, 6);` and at `insert` : `else {
      return;
    }` bad.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks ok, except

```
 empty(root);
 insert(root, 6);
```

After `empty(root);` root is not `NULL`, just some garbage, so you need to reassign it again ( `root = NULL;`) before you call `insert` function. The call to `insert` is also problematic, do it the same way you did before `root = insert (root, 6);`

Also do what Deduplicator advised in `empty` function. In case `root` is `NULL`, `empty` will crash, so check if the node is not NULL before you take  left and right pointers

Answer (score 0):

Repaired empty:

```
Node* empty(Node * node) {
    if(node) {
        empty(node->left);
        empty(node->right);
        free(node);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also, bad sequence in main (probably because you stopped after the errors...):

```
empty(root);
insert(root, 6);
inorder(root);
```

Replace with:

```
root = empty(root);
root = insert(root, 6);
inorder(root);
/*free(root);*/
```

Comment: `root = empty(root);` doesn't make much sense while `empty(Node*)` is **void**.

Comment: Ahh, yes, you propose to give it (Node*) type. That'll work, sorry.

Comment: @Cia: Just wanted to make the interface consistent.